# Architecture of server: location for components

Tags: web-services, architecture

I have following things:

1) Django + Tornado server (SQL DB is remote)

2) Redis

3) RabbitMQ

4) Landing page (just static)

5) E-mail server ([iRedMail](http://www.iredmail.org/)) is connected to the same DB as Django and Tornado.

My question: Is it Ok if I install all of them on the same physical server (instance)?

Or the best way that I separate it like (1,2,3) and (4,5)?

I'm worry about an E-mail server, because it seems will be used many resources..  On the other hand there are not more than 4 users who are registered there.

And what about security of an approach if it is installed on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is very specific to your application. However I can only give a general answer based on my personal experience, learned lessons, and best practices that I read elsewhere

You need to ask yourself a few questions that when answered, will help you figure out the best architecture to solve your problem:

## 1. Scalability

What are the usage patterns of each service in your solution? and could you scale some of them that are high demand, without scaling the other services?

> Would you (at some point) require a higher throughput from RabbitMQ service and add more instances in a cluster to keep up with the load, without having to scale up the email server as well?

## 2. Consistency

What strategies would you use to distribute the workload across multiple instances of the same service? (replication, partitioning, clustering, sharding, etc.)?

> RabbitMQ can work in a load-balanced cluster. but maybe your mail server cannot?

## 3. Efficiency

Some services can perform better if you scale them up (throw more CPU/RAM at them), not out (add more instances). choose wisely

## 4. Security

This is a big topic, but a few things I personally consider a must:

Most of your services expose endpoints (TCP sockets) that could be attacked. keeping everything behind a strict firewall and only exposing the most critical ports (web and mail server in your scenario)

Services should authenticate and verify each other (whenever possible) .. If one service got exposed, it should not compromise the entire system.